# Is there a skeuomorphism to flat design converter?

Tags: software-recommendation, flat-design

For those who have never heard of flat design, flat design involves the use of simple colours, shapes, and patterns. A good example would be this flat design pigeon set:
[image: A reporter pigeon, wizard pigeon, normal pigeon, blue pigeon, and dark blue pigeon]

What software can convert a skeuomorphic image (image that looks realistic, with gradients, metal, etc.) into a flat design one (without using color "polygons")?

Comment: I think your use of the word skeumorph is wrong or at least irrelevant / confusing in this context. What you are asking is not clear either... can you please rephrase?

Comment: ..oh; I think i understand what you mean now, but you are better off using the terms "realistic" or "photographs". Skeumorphics are plain wrong.

Comment: I'm sure I am using the term "skeuomorphic" correctly.

Comment: If you did, then your question makes even less sense:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeuomorph

Comment: This video can help explain what I mean by skeuomorphism: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=FoOWXF6Sc3M.

Comment: well, i doubt people would bother watching a video, when you could explain what you want with a couple of pictures.

Comment: ...and the answer is "with difficulty, but illustrator trace might be what you want"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracing in for example Illustrator is the closest you will get, if you do not want to draw. Since you do not show us any examples of images you want to "flatten", I am just guessing. But usually, the best results you will get from drawing manually "on top" of the image you want to "flatten".